# Oracle SQL to select rows with timestamp not more than 1 week ago?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select all rows which have a timestamp of less than a week ago in a column called `UPDATE_TIME` in a table called `generic`. From an earlier question I developed this script:

```
select * from generic where 'UPDATE_TIME' < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

But this is giving me this error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 92
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from generic
where timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(update_time,'SECOND') > current_timestamp - interval '7' day
```

- There is no `unix_timestamp()` in Oracle. This needs to be done using:

  ```
  timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + <number of seconds in epoch>
  ```

  to add the number of seconds they must be converted to an `interval` type. That's what

  ```
  numtodsinterval(update_time,'SECOND')
  ```

  is doing
- there is no `date_sub` in Oracle
- there is no `now()` in Oracle
- `'UPDATE_TIME'` is a string literal not a column name

If however `update_time` is a `date` or `timestamp` column, then the whole conversion is not necessary:

```
select *
from generic
where update_time > current_timestamp - interval '7' day
```

Comment: oh dear me, I mistakenly assumed that the question was in Oracle sql when it was actually mysql! will this take into account daylight savings though? I also need it to be the same throughout different timezones

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine: I _think_ that will work, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe the `timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'` part needs to be cast to a `timestamp with time zone` in order for that to work.

Comment: it takes ages though. I got a different query, thanks for your answer anyway! upvoted for answering the question and pointing out where I went wrong

Comment: well this is embarassing....I seem to have misunderstood what 'epoch time' means...sorry! Indeed it is a regular timestamp and not epoch time.